# style for the selected item in a select element in css

Tags: html, css, select

I tried to style the select element.

I do this:

```
option {
font-size: medium;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 30px;
font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
color: aliceblue;
```

}

After the user choose one of the option, I want the same style.
but this is return to the basic atyle/ what can I do to save the style to the selected one?

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL8jz90z/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
select {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

Comment: sorry! I edit the jsfiddle, and your solution doesnt help for this. see again please. thanks

Comment: It works just fine, assuming I understand your request correctly. https://jsfiddle.net/4n0n4ac7/

Comment: I take a fancy select. and I want to set the design to the values. but its not work. only with the simple select

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear as to what you aim to accomplish, but it's likely you want to achieve the following effect:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].onchange = function() {
  this.classList.add("selected");
};
```

```css
select,
option {
  font-size: medium;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}

select.selected,
option {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
  <option>four</option>
  <option>five</option>
  <option>six</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But it is not the same design